# Convert ISOString to unix epoch time

Tags: javascript, date

I have my date stored in localStorage as ISO string - `2018-08-29T06:30:00.000Z`

I want it to be stored as unix time instead i.e.`271708200` (This gives me 12 Aug 1978) when I parse it.

Hope the formats are clear. What would be the most accurate way to to this ?

Comment: `new Date(isoString).getTime() / 1000`

Comment: It gives me `1535697000 ` for date selected as 31 Aug 2018. These are ten digits. Wherever, in my example these are nine digits `271708200 `

Comment: @kushalvm What is your point? There are dates whose unix time is only one digit, and there are dates who have more than 20 digits. This happens with increasing numbers.

Comment: Ok. That only was the clarification :)

Comment: @kushalvm—UNIX time values are usually seconds, but ECMAScript values are milliseconds based on the same epoch, hence the `/ 1000`. For the timestamp "2018-08-29T06:30:00.000Z", the JS time value is 1535524200000, and UNIX is 1535524200.